# Yii. Не работает стандартное присваение данных

Tags: php, yii

Добавляю функционал для редактирования данных.
Однако стандартный для Yii способ присвоения данных из запроса в модель не срабатывает.

```
    if (isset($_POST['Something']))
    {
        $something->attributes = $_POST['Something'];//данные не присваиваются
        $something->save();
    }
```

Баг или фича?

**Update**
Пост данные содержит, проверенно.
Название ключей в $_POST['Something'] совпадает с названием полей модели.

Comment: Покажите:  

    var_dump( $_POST['Something'] );

Comment: @ReinRaus я юзаю xdebuger. В POST всё есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что свойства объекта Something не описаны коректно в rules

Comment: @VasyOk поле вообще не было описано. Объявил правило 'safe' и всё заработало.  
Поля? которые получают данные из вне, обязательно описывать в rules ?

Comment: Да, обязательно. Сам не раз с такой проблемой сталкивался :(

Answer (score 0):

полагаю, что $something - это модель, а присвоенные значения вашим способом простым сейвом не сохранятся, нужно сначала вызвать метод **validate()**, который валидирует корректность присвоенных значений, потом **save()**, либо вызвать метод **save(false)**, но в таком случае рискуете нарваться на неприятности.

Т.е., нужно сделать что-то подобное:

```
if($something->validate())
{
    $something->save();
}
```

Comment: Код недельной давности. Таже ситуация. Валидация к делу не относится.

                if (isset($_POST['ObjectAddForm']))
                {
                    $objectAddForm->attributes = $_POST['ObjectAddForm'];
                    //todo почему не происходит присваение обычным методом?
                    $objectAddForm->ups = $_POST['ObjectAddForm']['ups'];
                    $objectAddForm->battery = $_POST['ObjectAddForm']['battery'];
                    if ($objectAddForm->validate())
                    {
                      //    Прочий код
                    }
                 

Comment: Если верить ссылке: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

Те параметры, которые вы присваиваете, в модели должны быть помечены как safe

Comment: @nolka если я правильно понимаю, поля, принимающие данные, просто должны быть описаны в rules(), иначе они не скопируются.

Comment: почитайте доку по ссылке, все-таки)